# Can a tree with n vertices be colored with n colors according to greedy coloring?

Tags: graph-theory

This question is from a home assignment but it makes no sense to me.

> Construct a sequence of trees $(T_n)^∞_{n=1}$ with an ordering of their
>   vertices such that the greedy colouring algorithm uses n colours to
>   find a proper colouring of $T_n$.

From what I can tell, the greedy coloring algorithm always ends up using just two colors when coloring a tree regardless of the ordering of vertices but this question assumes otherwise. Am I wrong? I'm completely stuck on this.

Comment: ***the greedy coloring algorithm always ends up using just two colors when coloring a tree regardless of the ordering of vertices*** What if the tree is a path of $4$ vertices, and you color the two end vertices first? How many colors do you end up using in that case?

Comment: @bof That still only uses 3 colors for a tree with 4 vertices though, right?

Comment: The problem doesn't say that $T_n$ is a tree with $n$ vertices. Hint: $T_{n+1}$ may have twice as many vertices as $T_n$.

Comment: @bof No, but I sort of assumed so based on our lecture notes. The professor uses notation that implies that $T_n$ has $n$ vertices. Partial credit is offered for doing the coloring for $n=2,3,4,5$ too, so it sort of makes sense.

Comment: Your title asks a different question to the one in the body. The number of vertices is specified in the first one and not in the second.

Comment: You guys, I hadn't even considered that the tree doesn't have $n$ vertices! I just assumed so because of the way he uses $T_n$ in his lecture notes. My mind is blown right now. The question finally makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: The interpretation that $T_n$ must have $n$ vertices is impossible. There is only one tree with $3$ vertices and however you order the vertices the greedy coloring will only use $2$ colors.

Comment: @bof I see that now, the professor always used $T_n$ to mean a tree with $n$ vertices in the lecture notes, which is why this question was so confusing to me!

Comment: If fact, if $G$ is a graph on $n$ vertices, and if there is some ordering for which the greedy algorithm uses $n$ colors, then $G=K_n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a tree $T_n$ must have at least $2^{n-1}$ vertices. Here is a simple recursive construction where the tree $T_n$ has exactly $2^{n-1}$ vertices. In each case we order the vertices so that vertices of lower degree are colored before vertices of higher degree.

For $n=1$ let $T_1=P_1=K_1$.

For $n=2$ let $T_2=P_2=K_2$.

For $n=3$ let $T_3=P_4$; it has vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ and edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4$.

For $n=4$ start with the tree $T_3$ and add new vertices $v_1',v_2',v_3',v_4'$ and edges $v_1v_1',v_2v_2',v_3v_3',v_4v_4'$.

**Edit.** As requested in a comment, here is a detailed description and a proof.

Let $W_1,W_2,W_3,\dots$ be disjoint sets with $|W_1|=1$ and $|W_n|=2^{n-2}$ for $n\ge2$, so that $|W_n|=|W_1\cup\cdots\cup W_{n-1}|$ for $n\ge2$. Let $V_n=W_1\cup\cdots\cup W_n$.

Let $E_1=\varnothing$. For $n\ge2$ let $M_n$ be a matching between $W_n$ and $V_{n-1}=W_1\cup\cdots\cup W_{n-1}$ and let $E_n=E_{n-1}\cup M_n=M_2\cup\cdots\cup M_n$.

Plainly $T_n=(V_n,E_n)$ is a tree of order $2^{n-1}$. If $v\in W_i$ and $n\ge i$, then in the tree $T_n$ the vertex $v$ has no neighbors in $W_i$, exactly one neighbor in $W_j$ for each $j$ such that $i\lt j\le n$, and, if $i\ge2$, exactly one neighbor in $W_1\cup\cdots\cup W_{i-1}$; thus
$$\deg_{T_n}v=\begin{cases}
n-1\quad\quad\text{ if }\ \ i=1,\\
n-i+1\ \ \text{ if }\ \ i\ge2.\\
\end{cases}$$
I claim that, if the vertices of $T_n$ are ordered so that vertices of lower degree precede vertices of higher degree, then the greedy coloring of $T_n$ uses $n$ colors.

The proof is by induction on $n$. The claim is clearly true for $T_1=K_1$ and $T_2=K_2$. Suppose $n\ge3$. We start by coloring the leaves of $T_n$; these are precisely the elements of $W_n$, which is an independent set, so they all get the same color, call it red. It remains to color the vertices of $T_{n-1}$. Since
$$\deg_{T_{n-1}}v=\deg_{T_n}v-1$$
for $v\in V_{n-1}$, it follows from the inductive hypothesis that the greedy algorithm on $T_n$ will use $n-1$ colors on the vertices of $T_{n-1}$. Since each vertex of $T_{n-1}$ has a neighbor in $W_n$, no vertex of $T_{n-1}$ is colored red, so a total of $n$ colors are used on $T_n$.

Comment: i figured out how to construct n=5, 6, etc according to the pattern; and it does work when i color using order from low to high degree by hand--but is there a more rigorous way to write/show that  how this ordering leads to the usage of n colours? thanks

Comment: upvoted, thank you so much